# Template engine recommendations

Tags: java, templates

I'm looking for a template engine. Requirements:

- Runs on a JVM. Java is good; Jython, JRuby and the like, too...
- Can be used outside of servlets (unlike JSP)
- Is flexible wrt. to where the templates are stored (JSP and a lot of people require the templates to be stored in the FS). It should provide a template loading interface which one can implement or something like that
- Easy inclusion of parameterized templates- I really like JSP's tag fragments
- Good docs, nice code, etc., the usual suspects

I've looked at JSP- it's nearly perfect except for the servlet and filesystem coupling, Stringtemplate- I love the template syntax, but it fails on the filesystem coupling, the documentation is lacking and template groups and stuff are confusing, GXP, TAL, etc.

Ideas, thoughts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Suggestions for a Java-based templating engine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174204/suggestions-for-a-java-based-templating-engine)

Answer (score 2):

How about [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/)?

- full Java
- does not require servlets
- it has file, jar, classpath & URL resource loaders (and maybe more)
- templates can include other templates (if this is what you mean)
- has good tutorials, so far I could get what I needed from the docs

Answer (score 2):

If my memory serves, [FreeMaker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/) is decent - Suppose to be some sort of "Velocity, the next generation".

Answer (score 0):

maybe check out "JSTP", http://jstp.sourceforge.net/manual.html

its syntax is subset of JSP, therefore IDE support is excellent.

a "jstp" template is translated into a plain java class at build time. there is no runtime dependency.

"parameters" to a template should be passed by member fields. static typing all the way.

Bar.jstp

```
<%!                                        
    public String name;                    
%>

Hello <%= name %>
```

build converts it into Bar.java

```
public class Bar                                        
{                                                       
    public String name;                                 
    public void render(java.io.PrintWriter out)         
    {                                                   
        out.print("Hello ");                            
        out.print(String.valueOf(name));                
        ...                                             
    }                                                   
}
```

and you invoke the template by

```
Bar bar = new Bar();                              
bar.name = "John";                               
bar.render(..);
```

with typical "hotswap" you shouldn't have to restart serve when editing the template.

Answer (score 0):

What about [Snippetory](http://www.jproggy.org/snippetory)?

- It's full java, (even your logic is written in java!)
- Templates are loaded by the UriResolver, with implementations for calsspath, file system and URL.
- It can be used outside Servlets, for example as ad hoc template like `String.format`.
- It's entirely based on parametrized inclusion of templates.
- The docs are ok and it's much simpler than the script based engines, so you really don't need that much.
- And a new version with [great new freatures](http://snippetory.wordpress.com/feature-announcement-for-snippetory-0-9-5/) is coming soon, I think

Answer (score 0):

Try Mixer2. http://mixer2.org/
Mixer2 has no dependency for servlet-API.
You can store the template on String, java.io.File, and java.io.InputStream.

Answer (score 0):

Chunk, my no-nonsense template engine for Java, would be a good choice.

- Lightweight.
- Great docs with examples and recipes: http://www.x5software.com/chunk
- Standalone - no servlets required.
- Templates from filesystem, classpath, strings, a [webserver, or write your own template provider](http://www.x5software.com/chunk/examples/ChunkExample?example=net&loc=en_US#input-more-EG1).
- Based on simple templates with {$tags}.
- Templates can include other templates or even execute them as macros with a json-formatted dictionary of tag values.
- Looping, conditionals, filters, all the typical goodies.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of [Pebble](https://github.com/PebbleTemplates/pebble) which fits your criteria quite well.

Comment: I suggest elaborating on why this library would work for the user, at this time this is basically a link-only answer which is considered low quality.