# Mustache kind of String replacement in Java

Tags: java, string, velocity, handlebars.js, mustache

My application allows users to define few templates for text etc. Eg: one of the shortcuts could be `hi {{name}}, nice to meet you`.

I have a complex json which has name and lot of inner jsons. I am looking for a good mustache kind of implementation in java which can replace the values of json into the string. Currently I am iterating through each key and replacing the string but I am looking for more elegant solution which gives the users more power in their templating like loops, conditions etc similar to mustache/handlebars.

Though mustache for java looks good, I haven't seen any implementation which can replace with a JSON. All examples applies on an object but not on a json object. Looks to me that internally, it uses an object mapper to convert an object to object and somehow it applies that.

Perhaps I can convert JSON into a map and provide it.

Probably I am missing something. Thanks.

Comment: I take it you already looked at https://github.com/spullara/mustache.java -- The java implementation of mustache.js by Sam Pullara?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to convert the JSON string to a Java object. You can use a nested Map, Multimap or create you own object to represent the structure.

You probably want to use a JSON-serializer to create a java object from the JSON-string. Good solutions are [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/), [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or [Json-simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/).

Once you have a correct Java representation of the JSON, you can use a template engine to do the string replacement. Known libraries are [Freemarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/), [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) and [StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/)

Personally I recommend Jackson+Freemarker, but all are good solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Apache Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.5/user-guide.html#hello_velocity_world) it  does something very similar for property substitution in text.

Answer (score 0):

[Chunk](http://www.x5software.com/chunk/) is a very JSON-friendly template engine.  Loops & conditions, tag syntax is similar to Mustache, and you can reference nested associative arrays of data fairly elegantly right from the template.

See sample code for JSON + Chunk in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524352/better-template-language-needed/12755864#12755864).